# Problem running package in directory with whitespace on windows 10

Tags: windows, directory, whitespace, hadoop-yarn

Through the terminal I ran
`yarn create xxxxxxx-app` in a directory that had whitespace in the URL, but it failed because it couldn't understand the complete URL. So I changed to a directory that didn't have any spaces in it to run the same command and it failed using the same internal path as the previous.

The package installs the scripts and binaries where it should but when it tries to run them, it tries to use the original URL that has the whitespace and fails

Example in a directory with or without whitespace:

```
runs: C:\Users\First  Last\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\xxxxxxxxx-app
"C:\Users\First" isn't recognized as an internal or external command,
error Command failed.
```

So internally it uses the same command as the one that failed orginially even though it was run in another directory

both respond as follows:

```
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\First Last\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\xxxxxxxxxx-app
Arguments: ./xxxxxxxblog
Directory: C:\Users\First_Last\Github\David-Ventures1
```

Comment: Paths with spaces in them need to be surrounded by double quotes. `runs: "C:\Users\First  Last\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\xxxxxxxxx-app"`

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is that the package uses my user account no matter where I try to run the script, and unfortunately my user directory has whitespace in it.

So I need to remove the whitespace.... I tried a couple of times a little while ago but nearly bricked my computer...